# Using Moq to mimic functionality

Tags: c#, moq, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am trying to use Moq to make my container set a value using a SetVolume function that is void and takes in an int.

```
void SetValue(int CurrentValue);
```

Then I need to use the value that was set in another function.

```
void TakeValue(int value);
```

And the code that I'm trying to mimic in this is

```
CurrentValue -= value;
```

And this is what I've tried but haven't gotten any success.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MoqTest()
{
  Mock<IContainer> Container = new Mock<IContainer>();
  Container.Setup(cc => cc.SetValue(It.IsAny<int>()))
          .Callback<int>((i) => i = 8);

  UseContainer useContainer = new UseContainer(Container.Object);

  useContainer.StartUse(2); //Calls the TakeValue(2); inside

  Assert.AreEqual(6, useContainer.CurrentValue);
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is the rest of the code.

```
public interface IContainer
{
void TakeValue(int Value);

void SetValue(int Value);

int GetValue();

int SetValue(int value);
}
```

```
public class UseContainer
{
  IContainer Container;
  public UseContainer(IContainer Container){
    this.Container = Container;
  }

  public bool StartUse(int amount){
    Container.TakeValue(amount);
    return false;
  }

  public int CurrentValue {
    get
    {
      return Container.GetValue();
    }
    set
    {
      Container.SetValue(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide more code so that someone can see what your classes are doing. Also, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: When it gets the the Assert.AreEqual(6, useContainer.CurrentVolume); it doesn't give 6 it gives 0 .

Comment: Can you also share the code of `UseContainer` which you want to unit test?

Comment: You need to mock the behavior of Container.GetValue also. Since you are creating mock there is no actual object and no actual method of Container so the method calls which are not mocked will return the the default value.

Comment: @AnguishG have the test hold on to the values passed to the mock via a local variable.

Comment: Where did `CurrentValue` is set?